# ffmpeg -is it possible to increase a clip duration?

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, mp4

I currently have a jpeg file which I converted to an flv using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -b 180000 -i test.jpg test.mp4
```

Now, I want to increase the duration of this .mp4 clip, so the picture stays on the screen for more than a split second. Eventually, I hope to merge a stream of these files to create a slide show out of jpeg files.

Does anyone know how to increase the duration of a clip in ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3):

Looping the input and setting a duration should achieve the effect you want:

```
ffmpeg -loop_input -i test.jpg -t 10 test.mp4
```

Comment: FFMpeg has changed, instead of `-loop_input` use `-loop 1` now.

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like this should work (at least for a single image):

ffmpeg -loop_input -i picture.jpg -r 1 -vcodec flv -b 192k -i Music.mp3 -acodec copy -shortest output.flv

I bet you could get it working with multiple images by adding more inputs though I haven't tested.

(http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/280695-FFMPEG-Loop-input-video)